# Why I can't add animation clips to the list in the character animation tab in the inspector?

Tags: unity-game-engine

The character I downloaded is from Mixamo
When I click on the + (Plus) to add another Clip to the list it's automatic keep adding the same miaxmo.com clip which is is the t bone the hands are spread to the left and right. And instead I want to use the HumanoidWalk animation.

I tried to drag the HumanoidWalk animation to the Inspector but it didn't change much. And when clicking on the + (Plus) it's not giving me a list to select a clip from it's adding a new same t bone clip.

This is the default Inspector settings screenshot:

[image: Default]

And this screenshot is after I clicked the + (Pluse):

[image: Added]

And last a screenshot of the Rig tab:

[image: Rig tab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I worked like that the + button only gives you a copy of the full animation clips.

To get your animations you need to adjust the length of each copy.

For example:

- Frame 0 to 50 is Walking
- Frame 50 to 75 is Running
- Frame 75 to 150 is Attack

and so on...

Then it will generate your Animation Clips inside the model in the `Project` window.